# Desktop notifications from content scripts

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to show a simple desktop notification code from a content script, but it doesn't seem to work.. I have added the permissions in the maifest.json file. Is there a restriction on showing them from the content script ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, notifications use Chrome specific API, and the content script is only valid for general javascript etc... The [background page](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/background_pages.html) is where all chrome specific API's are capable of running... First you'll need to register your background page in the [manifest.json](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/overview.html#H3-3) file - like this:

```
 "background_page": "background.html",
```

Also in the manifest file, Allow the required permissions:

```
"permissions": [ "notifications" ],
```

Then your script in the background page should look like this :

```
<script>
setTimeout("setNotification();",1); 
function setNotification(){
  var n
  if (window.webkitNotifications.checkPermission() != 0){
    setNotification();
    return false;
  }
n = window.webkitNotifications.createHTMLNotification('http://www.your-notification-address.com');
n.show();}
</script>
```

Comment: If you set permissions for notifications in your extension manifest, you don't need to check for permissions. http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/notifications.html

Comment: Doesn't really explain how you can show a desktop notification that originates on a content script.

Comment: @Jonathan see my answer below

Answer (score 13):

You can't show notifications directly through a content script.
But, you **can** show them through the background page.

Your [manifest.js](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/manifest.html) should look something like this:

```json
    {
     "name": "Notify This",
     "version": "0.1",
     "permissions": [
        "notifications"
     ],
     "background_page": "background.html",
     "content_scripts": [
       {
        "matches": ["http://www.example.com/*"],
        "js": ["contentscript.js"]
       }
     ]
    }
```

Then use the [chrome.extension.sendRequest()](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/extension.html#method-sendRequest):

```js
    // in your contentscript.js
    chrome.extension.sendRequest({msg: "Sup?"}, function(response) { // optional callback - gets response
        console.log(response.returnMsg);
    });
```

And on the receiving end you should have a [onRequest](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/extension.html#event-onRequest) listener:

```js
    // in your background.html
    chrome.extension.onRequest.addListener(
      function(request, sender, sendResponse) {

            // Create a simple text notification:
        var notify = webkitNotifications.createNotification(
          '48.png',  // icon url - can be relative
          'Hello!',  // notification title
          request.msg  // notification body text
        );

        notify.show();

        setTimeout(function(){ notify.cancel(); },5000);
        sendResponse({returnMsg: "All good!"}); // optional response
      });
```

Comment: Thanks I had finally worked something like this out. They might as well just allow desktop notifications from content scripts. People get annoyed at Apple for such closed APIs, but it's not like Google where the web is meant to be more open...

Comment: This is the answer I was hoping to get, based on the title of the question.  Thanks!