# Desktop Notification on Chrome Extension not working

Tags: javascript, json, google-chrome-extension, manifest.json

After looking for info i cant get this to work, the last example i use was this [Desktop notifications from content scripts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3536621/desktop-notifications-from-content-scripts)

i have a background.html

```
<script src="bg.js" ></script>
```

bg.js

```
chrome.extension.onRequest.addListener(
  function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    // Create a simple text notification:
var notify = webkitNotifications.createNotification(
  'icon.png',  // icon url - can be relative
  'Hello!',  // notification title
  request.msg  // notification body text
);

notify.show();

setTimeout(function(){ notify.cancel(); },5000);
sendResponse({returnMsg: "All good!"}); // optional response
  });

chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {  
  chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tab.id, {});
});
```

manifest.json

```
  {
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "Checker",
  "description": "Checker",
  "version": "1.0",
    /*  "background":{
    "persistent":true,
    "page":"background.html"
    },
    "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.png"
    },

    */
    "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["https://www.google.es/*"],
      "js": ["jquery.min.js", "cs.js"],
      "run_at": "document_end"
    }
  ],
     "permissions": ["notifications","activeTab", "https://www.google.es/*"]
}
```

and finaly my cs.js (this is just the part of the code to call the notification... the rest gets executed just fine.

```
        chrome.extension.sendRequest({msg: "Sup?"}, function(response) { // optional callback - gets response
    console.log(response.returnMsg);
});
```

i like to get a desktop notification every time something changes on the page im looking

Comment: 1) `"permissions": ["notifications"]` is for [chrome.notifications API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/notifications), not webkitNotifications. 2) It could be https://crbug.com/825497

Comment: I have not bloked notification for my extension.

Comment: Then use chrome.notifications API like shown in the documentation and the [demo extensions](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/samples#search:notifications).

Comment: i did install the Drink water, but also does not show any popups...

Comment: Sounds like an OS problem or setting. See if it works in a portable Chrome freshly installed.