# Can't get notifications to work on Google Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, notifications

I'm writing a Google Chrome extension, but I can't get chrome notifications to work.
The goal (at least for testing purposes): to display a notification when the user clicks on the extension icon on the top right.
What's happening: clicking on the extension icon only displays the "Test body" text from `popup.html` but no notifications. Inspecting the console for the extension, I can see the result of the callback function: `Last error: undefined`.
**EDIT:** I've tried using Google's Notification API to test the functionality and it also seemed to not work. [This link](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=825497) talks about a bug on the Chrome notifications, so I worry that might be the issue. Any input about the bug would be appreciated.
Here is my code:
**manifest.json:**

```
{
  "name": "Test Extension",
  "description": "Test description",
  "version": "1.0",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "icons": { "16": "images/icon16.png", "48": "images/icon48.png", "128": "images/icon128.png" },
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["*://*.amazon.com/*buy*"],
      "js": ["js/content.js"]
    }
  ],
  "browser_action": {
    "default_popup": "html/popup.html",
    "default_title": "Test Extension"
  },
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["js/background.js"]
  },
  "permissions": [
    "notifications"
  ],
  "web_accessible_resources": ["images/icon48.png"]
}
```

**popup.html:**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Nubank Credit Control</title>
</head>
<body>
    <p>Test body</p>
    <script src="../js/popup.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**content.js:**

```js
chrome.runtime.sendMessage({
    url: window.location.href
});
```

**background.js:**

```js
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function () {
    const options = {
        type: "basic",
        iconUrl: chrome.extension.getURL("../images/icon48.png"),
        title: "This is the title",
        message: "This is the main message of the notification",
    };

    chrome.notifications.create("notifId", options, function() {console.log("Last error:", chrome.runtime.lastError);});
});
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Desktop notifications from content scripts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3536621/desktop-notifications-from-content-scripts)

Answer (score 1):

Actually, notifications can be triggered in popup.js as well. As far as I can see the issue is in how you call chrome.notifications.create().
The first parameter is optional but if you still want to pass it, it should be a valid notification id, not just 'notifId'.

For testing purposes this should be enough:

**manifest.json**

```
{
  "name": "Test Extension",
  "description": "Test description",
  "version": "1.0",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "browser_action": {
    "default_popup": "html/popup.html",
    "default_title": "Test Extension"
  },
  "permissions": [
    "notifications"
  ]
}
```

**popup.js**

```js
const options = {
    type: "basic",
    iconUrl: "../images/icon48.png",
    title: "Popup.js",
    message: "Hello from popup.js!"
};

chrome.notifications.create(options);
```

Or, in case of using background.js:

**manifest.json**

```
{
  "name": "Test Extension",
  "description": "Test description",
  "version": "1.0",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "browser_action": {
    "default_title": "Test Extension"
  },
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["js/background.js"]
  },
  "permissions": [
    "notifications"
  ]
}
```

**background.js**

```js
const options = {
  type: "basic",
  iconUrl: "../images/icon48.png",
  title: "Background.js",
  message: "Hello from background.js!"
};

chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function (){
  chrome.notifications.create(options);
});
```

Comment: It doesn't work for me. I get the confirmation and the notification id, but no notification is received.

Comment: Could be an issue with an incorrect path somewhere in your code? 
Also, it's important to reload the extension on chrome://extensions/ page after applying changes.
Which example did you try? With popup.js or background.js?
Anyway, here is a working example I have just double tested:
[https://github.com/konst8/chrome_notifications_example](https://github.com/konst8/chrome_notifications_example)

Comment: It was an issue with Windows Notifications, they were disabled. The extension was sending the notifications, but Windows was not showing them. Thank you

Answer (score -1):

The chrome.notifications API is only available in the background context, see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6189524/3862289 for a complete solution.

Comment: You're right, I changed that and updated my code above. It's still not working though.

Comment: You should be able to work around that bug by reinstalling it.